# Can't remove firewall block in iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm at my witts end with this. Why IPTables can't be easier to understand I will never know :/

Anyway, we are using iRedMail for our email system. My client has managed to lock himself out, after getting the SMTP setup wrong a few times. I can see his IP listed (changed for security :));

```
root@server:~#  iptables -L -n --line-numbers | grep 200.81.82.175
1    REJECT     all  --  200.81.82.175        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

but I can't for the life of me work out how to remove his IP!

I've literally spent the last hour trying to unblock him, but still no avail. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

On a side note - how can I whitelist his IP for ALL services? I think that'll be the easiest option once we have him unblocked!

Comment: Anything wrong with `iptables --delete`?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - how do I call that? I'm all for anything that makes it simpler!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you know the chain (for example `INPUT`) and rule number, deleting a rule is simply:

```
$ sudo iptables --delete INPUT 1
```

Where `INPUT` is the name of the chain, and `1` is the number of the rule in the list (obtained by running e.g. `iptables -L -n` as you have). **Don't do this blindly; always check your assumptions!**

The shorthand for `--delete` is `-D`, which works exactly the same.

You can also delete a rule matching particular criteria. For example, you could:

```
$ sudo iptables --delete INPUT -s 203.0.113.123 -j REJECT
```

Here, `--delete` is the analogue of `-I`/`--insert` and `-A`/`--append`, and wants the full rule specified. This is safer when the rule set might be modified as you work; as a consequence, it is the approach taken by e.g. `fail2ban`.

You can use `sudo iptables -S` to print the current rule set in a form that lends itself well to using in a corresponding `-D` command.

> how can I whitelist his IP for ALL services? I think that'll be the easiest option once we have him unblocked!

Whitelisting an IP address for all services is a bad idea. Instead, relax your blacklisting criteria somewhat so that normal but erroneous behavior by authorized users don't result in excessive blocking. For example, you could back off the fail2ban block timeout to something sensible, and ensure that blocks are applied only to the specific service that is being targetted.

Comment: Oh you star! Makes so much more sense now. What I ended up doing, was outputting `iptables -L -n > foo.txt`, and then looking at the chain, so I could see it was rule #1, so just did `iptables --delete fail2ban-postfix 1`. I'm going to make a note of how you do that, so I can do this with a lot less stress next time :)

Comment: @AndrewNewby Glad I was able to help. If you deal even semi-regularly with iptables, do set aside the time to look over the man page some time. It's not *that* incomprehensible, at least as long as you stay with the basics. (You can do a *lot* with iptables that is highly advanced and which benefits greatly from a deep understanding of the TCP/IP stack, but that's not necessary for working with simple firewall rules such as the one in your question here and now.)